# How do I extract hour from datetime column which has values in different formats in R?

Tags: r, datetime

Some sample values :

```
12/01/2011 11:49    
18-01-2011 9:50:45
```

I want the output as:

```
11   
09
```

The class of the datetime column is factor in my original dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with the [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html) package. 
As pointed out by @alistaire, the default solution does not parse correctly all the information (minutes and seconds) since the formats are inconsistent (one has seconds and the other not). Fortunately, the `truncated` parameter is here for that. We can set it to `1` since one element is missing.

> If `truncated` parameter is non-zero `ymd_hms` functions also check for truncated formats.

```
library(lubridate)

hour(dmy_hms(c("12/01/2011 11:49", "18-01-2011 9:50:45"), truncated = 1))

[1] 11  9
```

Or even better using pipeline notation `%>%` from the [magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) package -- love this name.

```
library(lubridate)    
library(magrittr)

c("12/01/2011 11:49", "18-01-2011 9:50:45") %>%
  dmy_hms(truncated = 1) %>%
  hour()

[1] 11  9
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Post corrected to mention magrittr.

Comment: They're not both dmy_hms, so it's actually parsing the minutes incorrectly if you look at the intermediate product. If you use `parse_date_time`, you can pass multiple orders, e.g. `lubridate::parse_date_time(datetimes, c('dmy hms', 'dmy hm'))`

Comment: [Docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1157/date-and-time/7018/parsing-dates-and-datetimes-from-strings-with-lubridate#t=201608281638168797469) for the above

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my answer to take your remark into account.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `sub` with regex:

```
dt <- c("12/01/2011 11:49", "18-01-2011 9:50:45")

sub(".*\\s(\\d{1,2}):.*", "\\1", as.character(dt))
# [1] "11" "9"
```

Or `str_extract` from `stringr`:

```
str_extract(as.character(dt), "(?<=\\s)(\\d{1,2})(?=:)")
# [1] "11" "9"
```